# Errors Dropping a Index in Python

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pymysql

I have these pymmsql index errors I created 3 indexes in my code and I want to drop them but they wouldn't drop I get these errors
Code:

```
DbConnect = 'Micros'
myDbConn = pymssql.connect(*******,"******", "*******",DbConnect)
cursor = myDbConn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""DROP INDEX [IF EXISTS]
                Micros ON payrolldata;""")
cursor.execute("""DROP INDEX [IF EXISTS]
               MainSort ON s20data,StoreSort ON s20data;""")
myDbConn.commit()
```

Error:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Python37-32\SqlVersionpr_import.py", line 840, in proceed
Micros ON payrolldata;""")
File "src\pymssql.pyx", line 465, in pymssql.Cursor.execute
pymssql.ProgrammingError: (102, b"Incorrect syntax near 'Micros'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 
15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
```

Comment: It is HIGHLY suspicious that your code uses `Micros` as both a database name and as an index name. Your second drop statement is just bonkers syntactically speaking. I suggest you first write your tsql statements using SSMS and get them working. Then migrate that code to your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax would be.

```
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS IndexName;
DROP INDEX IndexName;
```

Square brackets mean that parameter or part of statement is optional.
See documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15